# DP approach gives TLE

Tags: array, optimization, recursion

There is a question to basically find the largest sum in an array, such that no two elements are chosen adjacent to each other. The concept is to recursively calculate the sum, while considering and not considering every element, and skipping an element depending on whether the previous element was selected or not.

I understand that this problem requires the use of Dynamic Programming, but doing so still gives me a TLE. Although my code is very similar to the solution code, I cannot figure out why am I getting a TLE (>1.9 seconds).

Here is my code:

```
class Solution{
public:
long long dp[1010][510];
long long maxSum(vector<int> &B, int K, int N, int i){
    if (K == 0) return 0;
    else if(i >= N){
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    else{
        if (dp[i][K] != INT_MIN) return dp[i][K];
        dp[i][K] = max(maxSum(B, K, N, i+1), B[i] + maxSum(B, K-1, N, i+2));
        return dp[i][K];
    }
}

long long maximumBeauty(int N, int K, vector<int> &B){
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<1010; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<510; j++){
            dp[i][j] = INT_MIN;
        }
    }
    return maxSum(B, K, N, i);
}
};
```

and here is the given solution:

```
class Solution{
public:
long long dp(int i, int j, int N, int K, vector<int> &B,
             vector<vector<long long>> &cache){
    if(j >= K){
        return 0;
    }
    if(i >= N){
        return -1e15;
    }
    if(cache[i][j] != -1e18){
        return cache[i][j];
    }
    cache[i][j] = max((long long )B[i] + dp(i + 2, j + 1, N, K, B, cache),
                      dp(i + 1, j, N, K, B, cache));
    return cache[i][j];
}

long long maximumBeauty(int N, int K, vector<int> &B){
    vector<vector<long long>> cache(N, vector<long long> (K, -1e18));
    long long ans = dp(0, 0, N, K, B, cache);
    return ans;
}
};
```

I've tried initialising the DP array to different values, and calculate the sum individually and then compute the max, but I'm still getting a TLE. Please help me figure out the reason for getting a TLE in the first code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Most questions here need to be competitive challenges, so this is likely to be off-topic. We do allow [tag:tips] questions, so with some changes you could probably make this a valid [tag:tips] [tag:fastest-code]/[tag:fastest-algorithm] post, or alternatively it might be welcome on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you have any intention of converting this post to a code-golf challenge? 
I think it would make an interesting [code-golf problem](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/26009#26009), but I won't post it if you decide to use the idea yourself.

Comment: I posted this question on code-review as suggested by @Rydwolf Programs. The error was that INT_MIN was not sufficiently small enough. And I had to use a vector instead of an array.